# Why can I access my RDP using DDNS outside network (internet), but not from inside (LAN)?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, lan, wan, ddns

I have LTE provider with VPN feature (for my home network), so I used DDNS (no-ip.com) and configured my routers and other devices that I can access all my windows machines remotely.

For example. I can type myname.ddns.net:12345 on my Android device (rdp app) and I have no problem connecting with my devices while being outside my network. But as soon as I am back home and try to connect from inside LAN I need to specify my LAN IP or pc name in order to connect. For example: 192.168.1.100:12345 / MYPC:12345.

It is not possible to use ddns service inside my LAN. I don't understand why, and wish to know if it is possible to connect this way (using ddns inside LAN), because it is very problematic to constantly switch to different addresses. Maybe there are some options inside my router that I should change to accomplish my goal, or is it simply not possible ?

Outside using ddns hostname: no problem
Inside using ddns hostname rdp reports: Error code 0x104

"We couldn't connect to the remote PC because the PC can't be found. Please provide fully-qualified name or the IP address of the remote PC, and then try again."

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: My configuration: LTE --> Huawei B315s-22 (WAN IP: 31.62.XXX.XXX) (192.168.0.1) --> Asus RT-AC87U (192.168.1.1) --> RDP's. I hoped that at least Asus is a good router in this configuration with options that allow loopback, but I can't find it unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of sounding like Captain Obvious, why are you using a dynamic DNS within your home network to connect via RDP? There's a slider on the "EDIT" page that says "DON'T USE FOR LOCAL ADDRESS". Allowing you to have an alternate login for LAN access. It's redundant at best to use DDNS when there's absolutely no reason you should have to within the safety of your home network. Maybe an engineer thought it'd be amusing to write some code into the LINUX router kicking out RDP requests from a DDNS from within the intended route.